# Why merge sort algorithm giving array_Index_out_of_bound_exception?

Tags: java, mergesort

Here is my Java code which is giving exception which I am able to figure it out. can anyone help me where am i being wrong? I am commenting the lines where Exception is being shown.

```
static void mergesort(int[] array,int low,int high){
    if(low<high){
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        mergesort(array,low,mid);    //1
        mergesort(array,mid+1,high); //2
        merge(array,low,mid,high);   //3
    }
}
static void merge(int[] array,int low,int mid,int high){
    int[] array1 = new int[mid-low+2];
    int[] array2 = new int[high-mid+1];
    for(int i=0;i<array1.length-1;i++){
        array1[i] = array[i];
    }
    array1[array1.length-1] =  2147483640;
    for(int i=0;i<array2.length-1;i++){
        array2[i] = array[mid+i+1];
    }
    array2[array2.length-1] =  2147483640;
    for(int i=0,m=0,n=0;i<high;i++){
        if(array1[m]<array2[n]){    //4
            array[i] = array1[m];
            m++;
        }
        else{
            array[i] = array2[n];
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

If it required, here is the driver program. Comment shows exception line in driver program but I think it is because of exceptions in functions.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mergesort {
    public static void main(String[] str){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt(), array[] = new int[N];
        System.out.println("Enter elements in the array");
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        in.close();
        mergesort(array,0,N-1);   //5
        System.out.println("Sorted array is:");
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well if you have an exception, then you also have the line number where it has been thrown. Then this will greatly help you to find the problem, but us as well.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I have edited you can now look at it.

Comment: Please analyze the line `if(array1[m]<array2[n])`, exception is thrown here! That means that `m` or `n` takes values out of array length... Think twice, you build two array with less elements than the value `high`, but it may happens that the `for` loop increments `m` or `n` too much...

Comment: You need to debug your program to find out why it is trying to access an array using an invalid index.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I am trying, so far couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Take paper and pen (or trace the execution, or debug...). I gave you the reason, now you have some amount of work to review your coding logic.

Comment: @Jesper I think it is nor related question. I have solved it, it was of course due to index out of bound but it was result of a something different little problem associated with it's implementations.

Comment: Ok, from your question it wasn't really clear if you understood what this exception means.

Comment: @Jesper I know the meaning. It was more about the problem in particular case specifically. It is implementation related problem rather than syntactical at the core. Better if you remove Duplicate thing & lemme answer it.

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow doesn't let me remove the duplicate thing...